# Oracle PLSQL last used,opened tables program

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one problem. I'm starting with PL/SQL and I would like to write a program which will show me last used/opened tables is that somehow possible? If yes can you tell me how please? I'm using Oracle 11g database + SQL Developer.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add you code/efforts in question rather asking others to do?

Comment: I will do as soon as I will be home. But I have just tried few things which noone worked. I started with it just yesterday. That's why I ask how to do it cuz I need to understand it. I have never seen PL/SQL before. I was just doing some selects, updates and so on.

Comment: Oracle does not provide this information by default, because auditing generates overhead and different systems require different grains of auditing. Use AUDIT to start tracking this information (which requires DBA privileges). [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107).

Comment: Ouh... thank you very much I will try it as soon as I can. I'm glad that you guided me to some direction :) It's hard to start learning something on your own when you don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ALL_OBJECTS Data dictionary  with a object filter as ' TABLE' AND object_name as TABLE_NAME. You will get the last DDL performed.This doesnt require any special additional DBA privileges.

Sample Query: SELECT LAST_DDL_TIME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME';

Comment: I have tried it and it worked :) But it showed only time what I am looking for is that I will see user, operation he made and on what table. 

I have tried it with auditing as someone suggested before. It worked when I selected audit_trail, just the "SQL_TEXT" field was always NULL.

Have to rework it somehow.